# Recharts custom reference line when hovering axis

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using Recharts lib, and I need to create this effect on the hovered X Axis:

[image]

but I only get neither the gray background or the dotted line, because the only way to do it is within the Tooltip's `cursor` prop:

[image] [image]

```
<Tooltip
    //only BG:
    cursor={{ stroke: "#5C5C5C", opacity: 0.1, strokeWidth: 22 }}
    //only dotted line:
    cursor={{ strokeDasharray: "2 2", strokeWidth: "1", stroke: "#000" }}
  />
```

Any idea if it's possible?
i made a [codesandbox for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-zvl7yq?file=/src/App.tsx:1009-1205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [CustomizedCursor](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#cursor) that shows both a svg `rect` and a `line`. An
example implementation could be:

```tsx
const CustomCursor = (o: any) => {
  const point0 = o.points[0];
  if (!point0) {
    return null;
  }
  const options = Object.assign(
    {
      width: 0,
      fill: "#fff",
      opacity: 1,
      stroke: "#000",
      strokeWidth: 2,
      strokeDasharray: [4, 2]
    },
    o.options
  );
  return (
    <svg>
      <rect
        x={point0.x - options.width / 2}
        y={o.top}
        width={options.width}
        height={o.height}
        fill={o.options.fill}
        opacity={o.options.opacity}
      />
      <line
        x1={point0.x}
        y1={o.top}
        x2={point0.x}
        y2={o.top + o.height}
        stroke={o.options.stroke}
        strokeWidth={o.options.strokeWidth}
        strokeDasharray={o.options.strokeDasharray}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

You can use it to send both types of options (that is for both the `rect` and the `line`):

```tsx
<Tooltip
  cursor={
     <CustomCursor
        options={{
          stroke: "#000",
          strokeDasharray: [2, 2],
          strokeWidth: 1,
          width: 22,
          opacity: 0.1,
          fill: "#5C5C5C"
        }}
      />
    }
/>
```

Full code in [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-mf43yt?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! thank you!